# I want to store data in local from call log after phone call end in background

Tags: android

Currently, I making an application in which another person will get SMS after the call ended, By using PhoneStateChanger Listener we have only 3 option
1) IDLE
2) OFFHOOK
3) RINGING

but we don't have any CALL_ENDED Listener

so how can i done.

Answer (score 1):

RINGING -> OFFHOOK -> IDLE - Answered call (here IDLE is your CALL_ENDED state)

RINGING -> IDLE - Missed call

Comment: yeah but how i will check this condiont will you please eblorate.

Comment: @AshwinVishwakarma save previous state and check